# Will fetching members from a redis SET will fetch everything to memory?

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data-redis

I am using Spring Data Redis. If a Redis SET has millions of values, will fetching its members (am using [members() function](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/1.1.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/BoundSetOperations.html#members%28%29)) create a Java Set in the heap with a million values? Or is values fetched as and only required?

If all the values are fetched at one go, will it throw some out of memory error if the SET is huge? If so, how can I overcome that? I have got the same doubt with the range() of [LIST](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/1.1.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/BoundListOperations.html#range%28long,%20long%29) and [ZSET](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/1.1.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/BoundZSetOperations.html#range%28long,%20long%29).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SD Redis v 1.2 implementation for `RedisSet` has no lazy loading implementation.

But commands like `add` and `remove` are delegated to the underlying `RedisConnection` performing operations at the server without affecting any local data.

Using `RedisSet.iterator()` will execute `SMEMBERS` and load the entire response into memory, which is likely to use quite a lot of memory.

Same goes for the `List` and `Maps` implementation.

Comment: So I'll have to use LIST or ZSET instead of SET and then use range() to fetch limited number of members so as not to overwhelm my heap size?

Comment: just found out SCAN command. Don't know whether Spring Data Redis supports it currently

Comment: `SCAN` is currently not supported so you'd have to directly use the underlying redis connection (jedis directly supports scan, and you can emulate it for lettuce). But we're already working on SCAN support. See [Pull Request: #71](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/pull/71)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation doesn't mention anything about lazy loading, so it should be understood that all the elements of the set are fetched at once. Which will result in an `OutOfMemoryError` if you have huge sets.